# What's the difference between '\n' and EOF?

Tags: file, newline, eof

Can someone explain the difference between a '\n' (newline) and EOF which is also '\n'.

Is it like the last \n denotes the End Of File ?

Comment: *EOF which is also '\n'.* It's absolutely not. `\n` marks the end of a line. `EOF` marks the end of some input stream. `\n` has an actual ascii representation and is stored in the input stream (e.g. a file). `EOF` is a meta-character that is not stored anywhere. It is generated by API functions to tell the caller that the input stream has ended. There can be many `\n` characters in an input stream but only ever one `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

End-of-file(EOF) is a condition in a computer operating system where no more data can be read from a data source but by using "/n" at beginning or end of the code line it represent that will go on new line.
this two will used while both reading and writing data's